# Zero padding fourier of image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, fft

I'm trying to solve a question,
given an image f(x,y) at size N,M with fourier transform F.
we define function g, which its fourier transform G is define as follows:

G(x,y)=F(x,y) if x

which means that we pad the image with zeros.
I tried to check it out using matlab with this code:

```
i1 = imread('1.bmp');
i1 = im2double(i1);
k=fft2(i1);
newmat = padarray(k,[84,84],0,'post');
mat2=ifft2(newmat);
imshow(mat2);
```

for some reason im getting a complex matrix, which I can't really tell something intersting about,
what am I missing? (just to clarify, the image I tried has a size of 84x84).

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you are zero-padding your complex matrix `k` with real numbers. When then performing an ifft I would suspect that those real numbers would become complex. Try padding your complex matrix `k` with complex zeros '0+i0'. I don't know whether this is actually going to solve your problem, but worth a try.

Comment: thanks it works. please add it as an answer and il vote it...
another thing, what is the explanation for the result?(same image but darker...)

Comment: I have added it as an answer. I do not know why your image becomes darker. Try to pad equal amount of zeros on the end of it to see whether it has an impact. Again, only speculating.

Comment: WilliamW, it is normal that your image turns darker, because a consequence of zero padding before taking the fourier transform is that magnitudes decrease. Refer to [this topic](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8167/fft-zero-padding-amplitude-change) on the digital signal processing stack exchange if you are interested as to why, there is a pretty good explanation there. If you have doubled your image size, the luminosity should have decreased by a factor of two.

Comment: @FlorisSA you have a mistake, I padded after taking it to the fourier domain

Comment: @WilliamW: your selected answer is incorrect. Please take a second look, there is no way it solved your problem.

Comment: Also, @FlorisSA’s explanation for the dimming is correct.

Comment: @WilliamW as pointed out by others my answer is not correct and misleading. You should accept the other answers so I can delete my answer.

Comment: @WilliamW; sorry, I should have made myself clearer. Matlabs convention for the `fft()` and `ifft()` functions is to have the factor `1/N` appear in the expression of the inverse transform (see [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html#bvizm5c-7), the second equation is the IDFT). Therefore, if you increase the number of samples by a factor of two before you take the **inverse** transform, you will increase the `N` in this equation by a factor of two as well, thereby halving the amplitudes. Hope this makes more sense!

Comment: @matiastofteby you were correct, it was since 0 is not complex, i had to add this line: newmat=complex(newmat); , anyway if you want I can accept other answer or you can just update , since your answer was indeed correct.(just not fully)

Comment: @CrisLuengo also, I'm talking about padding the fft not before fft... so how is his answer relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The padding has to add high frequencies, which is not what you are doing. For a 1D FFT `F`, `F(2)` and `F(end)` correspond to the same frequency — in 2D this is exactly the same, for each image line along each image dimension. By padding with zeros by extending the array, you are creating a new `F(end)`. That value no longer matches the one in `F(2)`. For the inverse transform to be real-valued, those two values should be complex conjugates of each other.

The solution is to add the padding in the *middle* of the array, where the highest frequencies are. The easiest way to do this is to first use `fftshift` to move the zero frequency to the center of the array, then pad all around the array, then shift back:

```
k = fft2(i1);
k = fftshift(k);
k = padarray(k,[84,84]/2,'both');
k = ifftshift(k);
mat2 = ifft2(k);
```

This way you preserve the conjugate symmetry expected of the Fourier transform of a real-valued image.

---

It seems OP is confused about what happens when padding with zeros in different parts of the Fourier spectrum. Here's a little experiment:

```
% Create a test image, a simple Gaussian, purely real-valued
x = linspace(-3,3,84);
img = exp(-0.5*x.^2);
img = img.' * img;
imshow(img)
```

[image: input image]

```
% OP's method
k = fft2(img);
k = padarray(k,[84,84],0,'post');
k = complex(k); % This line does nothing
out = ifft2(k) * 4;
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(real(out)); title('real part')
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(imag(out)); title('imaginary part')
```

[image: output]

```
% Correct method
k = fft2(img);
k = fftshift(k);
k = padarray(k,[84,84]/2,'both');
k = ifftshift(k);
out = ifft2(k) * 4;
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(real(out)); title('real part')
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(imag(out)); title('imaginary part')
```

[image: output]

As you can see, when padding 'post', you introduce an asymmetry in the Fourier domain that translates to a non-real image in the spatial domain. In contrast, padding as I instructed in this answer leads to preserving the conjugate symmetry and hence a real-valued output (the imaginary part is all black).

(sorry for all the white space around the images)